# How can I keep Flurry from crashing when I don't yet have keys

Tags: android, flurry

sometimes my app cannot compose the key in time for flurry.  When it can't this is an exception that takes down the whole app.  Is there any way to set Flurry so that it does not crash under these circumstances?

Comment: You need to give more details.  It is not at all clear what you mean.  Where are you initalising flury?  Where is the crash occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I define the key like this:

```
public final static String FLURRY_KEY = "your key...";
```

This won't give any problems, please show how you are trying to implement it if this isn't a possible solution.